# Refine `RegionPlot3D`-result using `DiscretizeRegion` fails

Tags: regions

I try to improve the result created by `RegionPlot3D`:

Examplary `condition` (sorry for the huge size)

```
cond=(eta < 0 && -76.2826 (-1 + eta) <= 
    141. && ((2 xsi == 1 && 
       6.30783 (1 + eta) - 0.105948 (1 + zeta) >= 0 && (
        2.52313 (-1 + eta) - 
         1.1772 (0.643 (-1 + eta) + 0.036 (1 + zeta)))/(
        6.30783 (-1 + eta) - 0.105948 (1 + zeta)) >= 0) || ((
        2.52313 (eta + 2 xsi) - 
         1.1772 (0.643 (1 + eta) - 0.036 (1 + zeta)))/(
        6.30783 (eta + 2 xsi) + 0.105948 (1 + zeta)) >= 0 && 
       6.30783 >= -((
         0.105948 (1 + zeta))/(-1 + 2 xsi)) && (eta + 2 xsi == 
          0 || (9.81 < -((0.164771 (1 + zeta))/(eta + 2 xsi)) && 
           eta + 2 xsi < 0) || (eta + 2 xsi > 0 && 
           2 xsi < 1))) || (6.30783 - (0.105948 (1 + zeta))/(
         2 + eta - 2 xsi) >= 0 && (
        2.52313 (eta - 2 xsi) - 
         1.1772 (0.643 (-1 + eta) + 0.036 (1 + zeta)))/(
        6.30783 (eta - 2 xsi) - 0.105948 (1 + zeta)) >= 
        0 && ((2 + eta > 2 xsi && 
           2 xsi > 
            1) || (9.81 < -((
             0.164771 (1 + zeta))/(-1 + 2 xsi)) && (2 xsi < 1 || 
             eta + 2 xsi <= 0)))))) || (eta == 
    0 && ((2 xsi == 1 && 6.30783 - 0.105948 (1 + zeta) >= 0 && 
       0.4 - 0.75694/(6.30783 + 0.105948 (1 + zeta)) >= 
        0) || (2 xsi != 1 && -0.052974 (1 + zeta) >= 
        6.30783 (-1 + xsi) && 
       0.4 - 0.37847/(6.30783 xsi + 0.052974 (1 + zeta)) >= 
        0))) || (eta > 0 && 
   141. - 76.2826 (1 + eta) >= 
    0 && ((((0.4 - (0.75694 (1 + eta))/(
             6.30783 (eta + 2 xsi) + 0.105948 (1 + zeta)) >= 0 && 
           6.30783 <= -((0.105948 (1 + zeta))/(-1 + 2 xsi)) && -((
             0.105948 (1 + zeta))/(-2 + eta + 2 xsi)) <= 
            6.30783) || (9.81 > -((
             0.164771 (1 + zeta))/(-1 + 2 xsi)) && 
           0.4 - (0.75694 (-1 + eta))/(
             6.30783 (eta - 2 xsi) - 0.105948 (1 + zeta)) >= 
            0)) && (eta == 
          2 xsi || (eta < 2 xsi && 2 xsi < 1))) || (2 xsi == 
        1 && -0.105948 (1 + zeta) >= 6.30783 (-1 + eta) && 
       0.4 - (0.75694 (1 + eta))/(
         6.30783 (1 + eta) + 0.105948 (1 + zeta)) >= 
        0) || (0.4 - (0.75694 (1 + eta))/(
         6.30783 (eta + 2 xsi) + 0.105948 (1 + zeta)) >= 
        0 && ((2 xsi > 1 && 
           6.30783 >= -((0.105948 (1 + zeta))/(-2 + eta + 2 xsi)) && 
           eta + 2 xsi < 2) || (2 xsi < eta && 
           
           6.30783 <= -((0.105948 (1 + zeta))/(-1 + 2 xsi)) && -((
             0.105948 (1 + zeta))/(-2 + eta + 2 xsi)) <= 
            6.30783))) || (2 xsi < 
        eta && -((0.164771 (1 + zeta))/(-1 + 2 xsi)) < 9.81 && 
       9.81 - (0.164771 (1 + zeta))/(eta - 2 xsi) < 0 && 
       0.4 - (0.75694 (-1 + eta))/(
         6.30783 (eta - 2 xsi) - 0.105948 (1 + zeta)) >= 0))) 
RegionPlot3D[ cond, {xsi, 0, 1}, {eta, -1, 1}, {zeta, -1, 5} , PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 5}} , Mesh -> False  ] // Quiet
```

[image]

Result is ok but I would like to refine it. Using `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` works but takes long time.

That's why I would like to discretize the plotted region, but

```
DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[cond, {{xsi, 0, 1}, {eta, -1, 1}, {zeta, -1, 3}}]
```

gives error message  `DiscretizeRegion::drf: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region ImplicitRegion[<<2>>].`

What' s wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the original conditions of `cond`? It seems that it come from `Reduce` or `Solve`.

Comment: @cvgmt Thanks for your comment. Yes, `cond` comes from `Reduce`. I tried with the original condition and it works fine! That means `Reduce` makes the condition  worse such that `DiscretizeRegion` cannot handle it?

Comment: Yes. For the simplest example `reg1 = ImplicitRegion[{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 , z >= 0}, {x, y, z}] // 
   DiscretizeRegion;
cond = Reduce[{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 , z >= 0}, {x, y, z}, Reals];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[cond, {x, y, z}] // DiscretizeRegion`

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you, very helpful example.